# Using a X509 certificate for decryption

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, x509

I have some data of an X509v3 certificate that is used at a central licensing station. My question is is the following amount of information enough for me to decrypt data using C# code? And additionally, how are the certificate properties imported into a project? Do I have to create a certificate file in order to go on?

Known to me are:

- Subject
- Serial Number
- Issuer
- "root-ca"
- Public Key Algorithm: "rsaEncryption"
- RSA Modulus, 128 bytes
- RSA Public Key Exponent
- X509v3 Extended Key Usage: "critical"
- Signature Algorithm: "md5WithRSAEncryption", followed by 256 untitled bytes
- SHA1 Fingerprint

I do not have any certificate file. Excuse me if a similar question has already been answered, unfortunately I wasn't able to find one like mine.

Comment: What do you mean by "RSA Exponent"? In order to decrypt, you will need the private key exponent; the public key exponent will not suffice; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29#Decryption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your data is not enough. First of all, this is all *public* data. It doesn't contain a private key. A private key is used for decryption or signature generation. A public key is used for encryption and signature verification.

The .NET API is peculiar in that you can seemingly use a certificate to decrypt. This is not really the case; the certificate and private key *pair* are seen as one; only **if** the private key is included **then** you can actually decrypt. Personally I see this as a minor design mistake.

---

In principle you could create a certificate given the information. Basically you would have to generate a certificate with the same information and then replace the issuer and signature fields.

This is however not for the weak of heart; I recommend a few years of experience before you even try. If any information is missing from the list above you won't get a valid certificate / signature, *and you won't get any warning what is wrong*, just a failure. You've got one advantage though; if the signature verifies or fingerprint is identical to the one you've got then you *know* that you've succeeded.

You would not be able to decrypt of course; the private key would still be missing.

---

Note that the signature is the `256 untitled bytes`.

Answer (score 2):

This information is not enough. This data is a public key to encrypt data.
[RSAParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/En-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsaparameters(v=vs.110).aspx)