# .NET SslStream: How to extract session key?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, .net-core, sslstream

I'm writing a desktop application and wish to give users ability to verify network traffic, so they know they are not being abused. My application establishes a TLS connection to servers using [.NET's SslStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?view=netcore-3.1) with the [AuthenticateAsClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync?view=netcore-3.1) method. Wireshark users can decode TLS traffic using [NSS key logs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/Key_Log_Format). I can see that both Firefox and Chrome have options to logging encryption keys. How can I do the same in my .NET application? i.e. How can I extract the session key from `SslStream`, programatically?

Comment: I think you have to decrypt http body using provided certificate and inspect it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44705282/using-a-x509-certificate-for-decryption

Comment: No. I need the ephemeral key returned by Diffie-Hellman algorithm, else traffic can't be decoded by Wireshark.

Answer (score 4):

As of this writing, there is no way of doing that with dotnet's `SslStream`. Here's how to export the session keys using [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/):

```
internal static class BouncyCastleTls
{
    public static Stream WrapWithTls(Stream stream)
    {
        var client = new MyTlsClient();
        var tlsClientProtocol = new TlsClientProtocol(stream, new SecureRandom());
        tlsClientProtocol.Connect(client);
        return tlsClientProtocol.Stream;
    }
}

internal sealed class MyTlsClient : DefaultTlsClient
{
    public override TlsAuthentication GetAuthentication()
    {
        return new MyTlsAuthentication();
    }

    public override void NotifyHandshakeComplete()
    {
        var clientRandom = mContext.SecurityParameters.ClientRandom;
        var masterSecret = mContext.SecurityParameters.MasterSecret;

        Console.WriteLine("CLIENT_RANDOM {0} {1}", ToHex(clientRandom), ToHex(masterSecret));
    }

    private static string ToHex(byte[] bytes)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length * 2);
        for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; ++i)
            sb.Append($"{bytes[i]:x2}");
        return sb.ToString();
    }

}

internal sealed class MyTlsAuthentication : TlsAuthentication
{
    public void NotifyServerCertificate(Certificate serverCertificate)
    {
    }

    public TlsCredentials GetClientCredentials(CertificateRequest certificateRequest)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to combine this with the `HttpClient` ?